# Quartz trigger stacks up when first trigger is busy

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have a secondly trigger with `WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing`:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
   .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
   .WithCronSchedule("0/1 0/1 0/1 1/1 * ? *", x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
   .StartNow()
   .Build();
```

with following JobDetail:

```
var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<TestJob>()
   .WithIdentity(JobKey.Create("TestJob")).Build();
```

and `TestJob` itself with `DisallowConcurrentExecution`:

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution] 
public class TestJob : IJob
{
    private static int counter;

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        Console.WriteLine($"Job start on thread: {threadId}. datetime: {DateTime.Now}");
        if (counter++ < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sleeping.");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Job END on thread: {threadId}. datetime: {DateTime.Now}");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and here is how the scheduler is initialised:

```
var scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
scheduler.Start();
```

The output I get is:

> ```
> Job start on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:15
> Sleeping.
> Job END on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:20
> Job start on thread: 12. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:20
> Sleeping.
> Job END on thread: 12. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:25
> Job start on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:25
> Sleeping.
> Job END on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 12. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 12. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 15. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job END on thread: 14. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:30
> Job start on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:31
> Job END on thread: 13. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:31
> Job start on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:32
> Job END on thread: 6. datetime: 14/07/2020 9:45:32
> ```

As you can see, job is not concurrent which is good. but what I don't want is that the secondly job trigger stacks up while the job sleeps in the first 3 runs. After the 3 runs, all triggers which are stacked up are triggered immediately after each other. starting at `14/07/2020 9:45:30`, the job is called at least 15 times. This is the behaviour I don't want. I don't want that these calls stack up while a job is busy.

I thought I could use `WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing` for this, but it has no effect.

I hope this is clear, thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Probably [the misfireThreshold](https://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2009/03/so-you-think-you-understand.html) is related with what I'm getting. How can I configure this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, the problem relies in the misfire treshold.

If this timeout isn't passed, a trigger isn't considered misfired, so you need to reduce it.

You can do this:

```
NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
{
    .....,
    { "quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "1000" },
    .....
};
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
```

But it depends on the way you configure your quartz instance.

If you use the config file you can add:

```
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 1000
```